# Android: Making landscape view without layout-land?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I just want to group 4 buttons like this...

Portrait mode:

```
[1][2]
[3][4]
```

Landscape mode:

```
[1][2][3][4]
```

I dont want to hardcopy my Portrait mode xml-File and put it into the "layout-land" folder for this minor difference. Then, I have to modify two file when implementing new stuff.

Isnt that achievable through wraping it  up intelligently in some LinearLayouts? Something like this? ({} represent LinearLayouts)

```
{{[1][2]}{[3][4]}}
```

Comment: Its just for prototyping right now. Later I most likely will use layout-land

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Isnt that achievable through wraping it up intelligently in some LinearLayouts?

Not automatically. You would still need to dynamically change the outer `LinearLayout` between vertical and horizontal orientation. You can perhaps do that in your `onConfigurationChanged()` method.

Another option would be to have layouts in `res/layout` and `res/layout-land`, but use the `<include>` directive, so your buttons are defined once but are imported into their proper spots.

Comment: Can u show me an example, how u would do it using <include>? Thank you!

Comment: @OneWorld: Here is an article about `<include>`: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html  I would first copy your existing layout to `layout-land`, and make the adjustment so it works the way you want. Then, find the common portions between the two, pull those out into separate layout files and `<include>` them in your two main layout files. You may also wish to use the `<merge>` element: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html